# Convert Third-Party Time to MySQL DATETIME In Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am extracting information out of a third-party application, which includes a time value. The format is:

```
9/8/2015 7:05 PM
```

My goal is to convert this to a MySQL DATETIME value using a trigger.

So first, I tried the following directly in a SQL query:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9/8/2015 7:05 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i %p')
```

The result is:

```
2015-09-08 19:05:00
```

Great, this tells me that `STR_TO_DATE` likes my time and formatting, and is returning a `DATETIME` for me to store.

Then I moved this over to a trigger (`data` is the table / `oper_time` holds the third-party date and time):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `convert_time_to_mysql_format` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `data`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.oper_time = (select STR_TO_DATE(NEW.oper_time, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i %p'))
```

I changed `oper_time` to a `DATETIME`, ran the code and `NULL` is all I get in each of the fields for `oper_time`.

I changed oper_time to a `VARCHAR`, ran the code and now the properly formatted time shows up.

I'm confused... The documentation says `STR_TO_DATE` returns a `DATETIME`, so why can I not put that directly into a `DATETIME` column?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I'd guess that the problem lies with inserting the string into the DATETIME column? Even though you specify the trigger to fire BEFORE INSERT, maybe it's still throwing an error because of that initial mismatch. Does `SHOW WARNINGS` give you anything?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You want to change the the dateformat which came from a third party but you are using the same field to format the date and change it? `NEW.oper_time = ... STR_TO_DATE(NEW.oper_time...` It should be something like `NEW.oper_time = ... STR_TO_DATE(NEW.someThirdPartyDataCol...`

Comment: Jorge- First time working with SQL triggers, the goal here is to correct the time before it is committed to SQL. Maybe I am going about it wrong? miken32- Might be, I'll try sending it to a different table with a DATETIME field and see if that works.